# DataStore has defeated me

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to learn Kotlin and so far i was managing on my own, but alas i need help with understanding DataStore.
I want to save and load a simple String value. I did that with SharedPreferences with no issues but DataStore just isn't working no matter what i try and which "guide" i use.
What i'm currently stuck with:

```
private val Context.dataStore by preferencesDataStore("savedData")

class DataStorePrefs (context: Context){
private val dataStore = context.dataStore

companion object {
    val USER_ID = stringPreferencesKey("USER_ID")
}

suspend fun saveLogin(userId: String){
    dataStore.edit { it[USER_ID] = userId }
}

suspend fun restoreLogin(): String{
    val result = dataStore.data.map { it[USER_ID]?: "no id" }
    Log.e("result", result.toString())
    return result.toString()
}
```

I`m getting this: E/result: com.evolve.recyclerview.data.DataStorePrefs$restoreLogin$$inlined$map$1@7dde190

So how do i actually get the value from a Flow? I tried to use dataStore.data.collect but it just gets stuck on it never returning anything.

Comment: If you're still interested, I got a great answer on a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77770734/confusion-about-what-datastore-methods-are-supported/77771826#77771826

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that

```
dataStore.data.map { it[USER_ID]?: "no id" }.first()
```

gets me the String.

Answer (score 0):

```
private val Context.dataStore by preferencesDataStore("savedData")

class DataStorePrefs(context: Context){

    companion object {
        val USER_ID = stringPreferencesKey("USER_ID")
    }

    suspend fun saveLogin(userId: String){
        dataStore.edit { it[USER_ID] = userId }
    }

    val myFlow: Flow<String> =  
        dataStore.data.map { it[USER_ID]?: "no id" }
}
```

Then somewhere else:

```
myFlow.collect {
   doSomething(it)
}
```

Comment: But what should i do in "doSomething" to return the string? The .first() did exactly what i needed even though i don'n quite understand what it does exactly and i'm pretty sure it's not the ideal/proper solution.