# Confusion about what DataStore methods are supported

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences, kotlin-coroutines

TLDR: I've been fighting most of the day today with `DataStore`, more specifically why most suspend methods seem to just hang forever and only `map {}.first` worked for me to get the `Preferences` object.

---

### Context

I'm writing a small Android app with very lightweight use of local storage:

1. I need to read all settings from local storage at app startup (doesn't need to be blocking though).
2. As the user interacts with the app, update the local storage. No need to read anymore.

---

### Examples

What finally worked:

```
val preferences =
            context.transliterationStatesDataStore.data.firstOrNull() ?: return
```

```
val preferences =
            context.dataStore.data.map { preferences -> preferences }
                .first()
```

What I've tried before:

```
val preferences =
            context.dataStore.data.map { preferences -> preferences }
                .lastOrNull() ?: return
```

```
val preferences =
            context.dataStore.data.lastOrNull() ?: return
```

```
Log.d("debug", context.dataStore.data.count().toString())
```

---

### Confusion

I'm confused why:

1. `.count()` didn't work (suspended forever)
2. `.lastOrNull()` didn't work (suspended forever)
3. It feels wrong to read the **first** value of the flow when what I want is the **latest** version of the `Preferences` from disk.

---

There is a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68245912/datastore-has-defeated-me) but it didn't receive any answers beyond more data points from the author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Flow from DataStore is infinite because it monitors the storage in perpetuity so it can emit every time the value changes. Since it's infinite, functions that collect the flow until its final value to get its total `count` (infinity) or `last` value (which never comes) will hang forever.

Flows are cold. When you call `first()`, *then* the flow queries the data store to get the current value to emit for collection. It will be the most up-to-date value. `first()` is the correct way to get the latest value only. If you want to continually react to the latest value as new values are posted, then you can use `collect { }` instead of `first()`.

You will find that most Flows are infinite if they *monitor* something like storage or a database. For example, Flows returned by Room database functions are all infinite, just like the ones from DataStore.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. [`.count()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/count.html) didn't work (suspended forever)

This value will **never** be resolved for as long as the `Flow` keeps emitting new values (which `DataStore.data` will, or unless the `Flow` is cancelled) - [this is the implementation of the `.count()` method](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/kotlinx-coroutines-core/common/src/flow/terminal/Count.kt#L15):

```
public suspend fun <T> Flow<T>.count(): Int  {
    var i = 0
    collect {
        ++i
    }

    return i
}
```

> 2. [`.lastOrNull()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/last-or-null.html) didn't work (suspended forever)

Same goes for `.lastOrNull()`, it'll suspend until the last value is emitted, which will never happen ([source code](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/kotlinx-coroutines-core/common/src/flow/terminal/Reduce.kt#L165)):

```
public suspend fun <T> Flow<T>.lastOrNull(): T? {
    var result: T? = null
    collect {
        result = it
    }
    return result
}
```

> 3. It feels wrong to read the first value of the flow when what I want is the latest version of the Preferences from disk.

That's what collecting from the `Flow` is for, that way you'll always get the latest values:

```
yourPreferenceDataStore.data.collect {
  // Get latest updates here
  println(it)
}

// Or if you want to get a specific data from the DataStore
val whateverData = yourPreferenceDataStore.data.map { it.whatever }
```

If you need to use it in Compose, you can use `collectAsState`/`collectAsStateWithLifecycle` to collect it as a Compose `State` for use in your composables:

```
@Composable
fun MyScreen() {
  val yourData by dataStore.data.collectAsStateWithLifecycle(initialValue = /* initial value */)
}
```